Where/How to install a Qt Linux application so that it’s accessible to all users but runs with sudo privileges on startup
I'm developing a Qt application for Linux that overlays a watermark on all screens.
The application is intended for non-admin users, and I need to ensure that they cannot close it or modify its files, as that would defeat its purpose.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I installed the app in /usr/local/share/myapp so that it's accessible to all users, but only admin users can execute and modify it (as it requires sudo privileges for reading/writing files in this directory).

I created a systemd service to run the application on startup.


However, I have a couple of issues:

Is my approach of installing the app in /usr/local/share/myapp and requiring sudo for regular users to run it the best way to prevent them from tampering with the app's files or closing it?

The systemd service works fine for console apps, but when it tries to run the Qt GUI app, it fails. I suspect it's because there's no display available when running the service through systemd.


How can I resolve the issue with the GUI not displaying when launched by systemd? Any advice on improving the security setup for preventing non-admin users from closing or altering the app would also be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

You have two distinct problems, and we should normally ask only one question per post. I suggest you to start by focusing on the second one, since it prevents the program to load to begin with; we need to know more about the environment, though: what graphical system is used, how users access/login, possible desktop/window manager(s), level of customization left to the users, etc.

For problem 2, to work with it: open terminal window. Launch root login shell, probably with command sudo su - and then figure out how to run GUI apps from that. ... Or ask a question, maybe at Linux stackexchange site rather than here.

Yes, probably more appropriate to [unix.se]. Delete here, post there. OR restructure your question as programming code that isn't working, including exact text of error messages. Also read about [mcve] plus the [help] sections for "How-to-ask" and "On-Topic". Good luck.

Question 1 is two questions in one. Installing binaries into eg /usr/local/bin and making them owned by root is sufficient to prevent tampering. Running the program under another user effectively prevents them from killing it.

For your second question, I think this might be the dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676418/324221
